# redirect to index if status code 500

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've added this to my show action on my controller:

```
redirect_to shows_path, status: 500
```

doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

I just want it to go to show index whenever there's a internal server error (500) for the show action.

Comment: Just a somewhat related point; is there a reason you want this? This might really confuse your users. They won't realize there was a server error at first, and will keep trying to go back to the page. Seeing an error page would be much more helpful to them.

Comment: Or do both `/index.html#show_an_error_bar`

Comment: I agree, but I'm forwarding traffic from another rails app using the title, guess I can add alert: "the page you're looking for doesn't exist so we brought you here instead"

Comment: @user2612713 Yeah; that would probably be the best option, I think. Makes sense why. As for an answer; I don't know, but maybe a useful edit would be to add a tag or two that you know are really related to this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think this would be a bad thing to do from a usability standpoint, you could add a rescue clause that is only triggered when an exception is thrown:

```
def show
  # do whatever you do
rescue
  redirect_to shows_path, error: 'Something bad happened'
end
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but i'll take your advice and implement a custom 500 error and just put a link to index.